# Creating a loop for segments within a vector that give return values for each corresponding segment

Tags: r, loops, vector, return, rscript

I've created a vector "numGrades" of 100 random numbers to represent values within a grading system. I need to write a "for" loop that takes segments of numerical grades and returns a vector of corresponding letter grades i.e.: 90+ = "A", 80-89 = "B", 70-79 = "C", 60-69 = "D", 0-59 = "F". I want to be able to run numGrades to return the corresponding letter grade for example: numGrades = [72, 65, 93] returning = ["C", "D", "A"] with the loop handling vectors of any length. **This is what I have tried so far individually. All of these loops have returned warnings:**

```
set.seed(43)
numGrades <- sample(0:100, 100, replace=FALSE)

for (i in numGrades )
  if(91 <= numGrades[i]) {
    numGrades[i] <- "A"
  } else if (80 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 90) {
    numGrades[i] =="B"
  } else if (70 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 79) {
    numGrades[i] =="C"
  } else if (60 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 69) {
    numGrades[i] =="D"
  } else if (0 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 59) {
    numGrades[i] =="F"
  }
```

It's saying:

```
Error in if (91 <= numGrades[i]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

**New Edit (Returns for grades >= 91 only):**

```
numGrades <- (0:100)
for (i in 1:length(numGrades ))
  if(91 <= numGrades[i]) {
    numGrades[i] <- "A"
  } else if (80 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 90) {
    numGrades[i] =="B"
  } else if (70 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 79) {
    numGrades[i] =="C"
  } else if (60 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 69) {
    numGrades[i] =="D"
  } else if (0 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 59) {
    numGrades[i] =="F"
  }
```

**Working Rough Draft**

```
ltrGrades <- (0:100)
numGrades <- character(length(ltrGrades))

for (i in 1:length(ltrGrades ))
  if(any(ltrGrades[i] == 91:100)) {
    numGrades[i] <- "A"
  } else if (any(ltrGrades[i] == 80:90)) {
    numGrades[i] <- "B"
  } else if (any(ltrGrades[i] == 70:79)) {
    numGrades[i] <- "C"
  } else if (any(ltrGrades[i] == 60:69)) {
    numGrades[i] <- "D"
  } else if (any(ltrGrades[i] == 0:59)) {
    numGrades[i] <- "F"
  }
```

Comment: `cut(numGrades, c(-1, 60, 70, 80, 90, 101), labels=c("F","D","C","B","A"))`

Comment: How would I write that into the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some fundamental R syntax problems with your code.

```r
(numGrades[i]) c(80:90))
(numGrades[i]) >=80 && <=89)
(numGrades[i]) ==80:89 )
```

Several alternatives, most inefficient:

```r
(80 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] < 90)    # the most basic
(dplyr::between(numGrades[i], 80, 90))      # if dplyr is loaded
(data.table::between(numGrades[i], 80, 90)) # if data.table is available
(numGrades[i] %in% 80:89)                   # works only if all grades are perfectly integral
(any(numGrades[i] == 80:89))                # ditto
```

Why are they wrong?

- `(numGrades[i]) c(80:90))`, because there is not operator
- `(numGrades[i]) >=80 && <=89)`, R does not infer them as you suggest, every time you do an (in)equality test you need to specify both the LHS and RHS for each one; similarly, unlikely many languages, R does not "chain" them, so `(80 <= numGrades[i] <= 89)` will not work
- `(numGrades[i]) ==80:89 )` is getting closer, but `if`/`else` statements require a single comparison; in this case, you are comparing one number with a sequence (range) of 10, so the reply from this is length 10. It must be length 1.

Bottom line, though, is that you do not need a loop.

```r
# set.seed(43)
numGrades <- sample(0:100, 100, replace=FALSE)
cut(numGrades, c(-1, 60, 70, 80, 90, 101), labels=c("F","D","C","B","A"))
#   [1] F A F D F F D F F C F F F F F B F A F F C A F F F F A F A F C C C B F
#  [36] F F F B A F F F A B B C D F F F B D F F B D D B F F F F F F D F A F F
#  [71] F F F F B F D F A F F F F F A B F F F C F F F D D C C F F F
# Levels: F D C B A
```

or if you don't like or understand what a `factor` is, then

```r
as.character(cut(numGrades, c(-1, 60, 70, 80, 90, 101), labels=c("F","D","C","B","A")))
#   [1] "F" "A" "F" "D" "F" "F" "D" "F" "F" "C" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "B" "F"
#  [18] "A" "F" "F" "C" "A" "F" "F" "F" "F" "A" "F" "A" "F" "C" "C" "C" "B"
#  [35] "F" "F" "F" "F" "B" "A" "F" "F" "F" "A" "B" "B" "C" "D" "F" "F" "F"
#  [52] "B" "D" "F" "F" "B" "D" "D" "B" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "D" "F" "A"
#  [69] "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "B" "F" "D" "F" "A" "F" "F" "F" "F" "F" "A"
#  [86] "B" "F" "F" "F" "C" "F" "F" "F" "D" "D" "C" "C" "F" "F" "F"
```

---

**EDIT**

I just noticed something else about your code.

When you start, `numGrades` is either numeric or integer. However, since it is a vector, the first time you assign a letter to one of its elements, the entire vector is converted to a `character` vector. The second pass through the `for` loop will try to compare a number with a string, which will not do a numeric comparison, try `8 < "75"` for why this will fail.

As a workaround for this:

```r
ltrGrades <- character(length(numGrades))
for (i in 1:length(numGrades ))
  if(91 <= numGrades[i]) {
    ltrGrades[i] <- "A"
  } else if (80 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 90) {
    ltrGrades[i] <- "B"
  } else if (70 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 79) {
    ltrGrades[i] <- "C"
  } else if (60 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 69) {
    ltrGrades[i] <- "D"
  } else if (0 <= numGrades[i] & numGrades[i] <= 59) {
    ltrGrades[i] <- "F"
  }
```

Comment: I should've been more clear. I do need to have this written as a "for loop", so I will edit the question to clarify. Also, I don't have data.table. Thanks for the feedback on the incorrect stuff.

Comment: @ConnerM Why does it need to be written as a for-loop?

Comment: My answer does include the corrections necessary, but when you say *"I do need to have this written as a 'for loop","* are you saying that this is an assignment, and you are being forced to do it in an inefficient manner? That's fine. Know that many answerers on SO will try to give you the most efficient answer, assuming (typically correctly) that askers on SO may not know enough about R to do it the "best-practices way".

Comment: Yes, it is for an assignment that's asking for it to be written in a "for loop". And I'm still learning the terms and functions so the simpler the better.

Comment: I will edit the post to show what I have now. It's saying there is "Error in if (91 <= numGrades[i]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: (1) When you edit your question, please do not remove still-relevant information, such as the errant attempts at your chained conditionals. (2) You changed your code significantly enough: you previously had `for (i in 1:length(numGrades) )`, which should return `1 2 3 4 ... length(numGrades)`, which means `i` is an index to the vector; now you have `for (i in numGrades )`, which will return `48 91 5 69 30 ...`, which means `i` is a *value*, not an index ... but you are still treating `i` like an index on the vector. Unfortunately, that includes 0, where `numGrades[0]` will never work.

Comment: BTW, you have a typo in your most recent edit, `numgrades` versus `numGrades`. Please type/copy/paste actual code that was actually used, as I got a very different error when I tried your code as-is.

Comment: In regard to the previous attempts in the original questions, I'll keep that in mind. As for the new edit, I fixed the typo. Also, I should be using 1:length?

Comment: I prefer the more resilient `seq_len(length(x))`: if `length(x)` is ever 0, you'll get `1:0` which is actually of length 2, when you would expect it to return nothing (`integer(0)`). In cases where you need to loop over values but change or retain something for each instance (such as changing the value or assigning a letter), then you should be indexing.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect my new code. It's returning values "A" for anything >= 91 but for anything below 91, it returns x-1.

Comment: The new edit did fix the error of conversion from int to chr. But it still won't return grade values for anything below 91. Also, how would I allow for it to return more than one value at a time (increasing dimension)?

Comment: That's what I get for copying your code and doing an incomplete test, I should practice what I preach. Your code was using `==` as an assignment operator.

Comment: By "return more than one value at a time", just use multiple vectors within each `if` clause. For instance, `if (numGrades[i] >= 90) { ltrGrades[i] <- "A" ; someOther[i] <- pi; aThirdVariable[i] <- "whoknows"; } else if (...`.

Comment: I need to pull from the single vector throughout. I've edited it (using your previous advice) and it now can pull any number to bring me a letter using numGrades [x]. I'm wondering if there's a way to add dimension to have a string of values returned.